# News post with multiple permalinks? When opened from different page

Tags: custom-post-types, php, posts, permalinks

I’ve got a question. Maybe it’s something existing and I don’t know the name. Or maybe it’s something custom.

I’ve got a post type for news. The news posts have categories.
These are some examples of separate news items

- News item 1.

  - Category “purple”
- News item 2.

  - Category “purple”
  - Category “red”
- News item 3.

  - Category “red”

I have 3 pages where I show and filter the news:

- www.domain.com/news (This shows all the news)
- www.domain.com/purple/news (This shows all the purple news)
- www.domain.com/red/news (This shows all the purple news)

Showing a filtered post grid on each news page is not the problem. The problem is displaying them.
By default the permalinks of each news post is:

- www.domain.com/news/news-item-1
- www.domain.com/news/news-item-2
- www.domain.com/news/news-item-3

And this is fine for the news on www.domain.com/news/

But now I want to display the category news items like following:
From www.domain.com/**purple**/news I want to click on the news item and open it like:

- www.domain.com/**purple**/news/news-item-1
- www.domain.com/**purple**/news/news-item-2

And from www.domain.com/**red**/news I want to click on the news item and open it like:

- www.domain.com/**red**/news/news-item-2
- www.domain.com/**red**/news/news-item-3

### The Question

How do I get the news on the category news pages to open and show the items on the preferred url? (this should also show up in the sitemap.xml)

Comment: And why do you want to reverse order of slugs in the URL? Why not use `example.com/news/purple/` and `example.com/news/purple/first-news-slug/` instead? (It's much more natural and intuitive...)

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż, because example.com/purple is sort of a landing page for this category. With a new page and some other pages under it.

Comment: Posts should have a single canonical URL, otherwise search engines will penalize you for duplicate content.

Comment: @Milo, thanks for bringing that to my attention. I'll use "rel="canonical" link element" for this duplicates to fix it. Source: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66359?hl=en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution. This is the abstracted version:

```
add_rewrite_rule(
     '^red\/news([^/]*)/?',
     'index.php?event=$matches[1]',
     'top'
);

//Ensure the $wp_rewrite global is loaded
global $wp_rewrite;
//Call flush_rules() as a method of the $wp_rewrite object
$wp_rewrite->flush_rules( false );
```

In the actual function I've made an array with the pages I want to redirect. (Source and destination) and run foreach and flush the rules after.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Custom Permalinks plugin. you can create and edit each post and category link very essay.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-permalinks/
Try this once